# Right menu (Navbar-right) misaligned on first load on IE8 using Bootstrap V 3.0.0

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC4 website to be run on IE 8. We are creating navigation headers with Bootstrap nav controls. I find that the right menu items are getting misaligned on first time rendering, if I hit F5, the alignment is proper again. We tried to debug using F12 debugger and Fiddler to see if scripts and CSS files are getting rendered, they do render well.

What could possibly be the reason it is getting misaligned at first shot and how is it re-aligning on refresh?

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Company Logo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="#">Project name</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Admin</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
         </ul>
       <div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">My contacts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">State</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PROD</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Welcome, Username</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Its not Bootstrap 3.3.0 it is V 3.0.0. Sorry about the typo

Comment: IE8 requires Respond.js or similar to render correctly. If you're using that, it's possible it hasn't had time to parse the document yet, or you're loading it too late in the page.